# should I test SSL / HTTPS routes locally in a rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, ssl, https

I'm wondering what the best practice is concerning test that certain urls use certain protocols. Do I have to set up an SSL cert locally?

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to set up an SSL cert locally. You can fake an HTTPS request in your tests with something like:

```
request.env['HTTPS'] = 'on'
```

Comment: You can pass this header to the get, post, etc. call in the third argument, e.g. `get '/', nil, 'HTTPS' => 'on'` in your integration tests

Answer (score 0):

If your concern is specifically about HTTPS connections testing, I would suggest setting up your own test CA and issuing certificates for your machine. Then, import the CA certificate into your test clients. This will be far more realistic than tests where you would just bypass the certificate verification.

Avoid certificates issued to IP addresses, give names to your servers. Even if you don't have a DNS server, set the machine names in the `hosts` files of the client machines.

There are a number of tools that can help you set up a small CA. TinyCA is one of them, for example.